# How can I use npm 2.0 on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: npm, ibm-cloud

Is it possible to use npm version 2 on Bluemix? By default it runs version 1.4, but I want to "install" a package from a local directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to configure the npm version when using the community open source Node.js buildpack and setting the npm version in my `package.json`.  See below.

```
"engines": {
  "npm": "^2.1.0"
}

cf push mynodeapp -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
```

Not sure if this is possible using the default Node.js buildpack yet.

In the staging output, you should see:
       Npm engine:          ^2.1.0

Comment: I should have mentioned that the requirement is to use it with the default buildpack. Haven't tried node 0.12 though.

Comment: Sorry, just confirmed that at this point you can not configure the npm version (currently: 1.4.28) with the default Node.js buildpack. I recommend you to check again in a few weeks.

Comment: You can now do this on the default Bluemix Node.js buildpack as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to modify package.json like below:

```
"engines": {
  "npm": "^2.1.0"
}
```

After that you can push your app to bluemix and verify the same in staging output.
Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You could package the dependency inside your application directory, and create a "preinstall" script that will run an `npm install` on that dependency:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "preinstall": "npm install relative/path/to/module"
  },
```

This should work locally and on Bluemix.  Note that "postinstall" is also an option.